# Is it possible to make a scroll bar outside of the content it's scrolling?

Tags: css

Now, if the background weren't textured I could do some CSS trickery with padding / margins and such.

When you do a scrollable div (which is what I'm doing now) like this:

```
overflow: auto;
height: 80%;
```

the scrollbar appears on the inside of the div that is being scrolled

Here is a mock up of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/p75LE/2/

?

Comment: yeah, kinda. is there anyway to style the scrollbar like I have it? or is that a completely different issue?  You've proved me wrong on my prior assumptions: http://jsfiddle.net/p75LE/3/ (with background)

Comment: that's another question - i know webkit browsers support custom scrollbars (http://css-tricks.com/9130-custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) - but for cross-browser support you'll need a script like http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar